# Get inline CSS property value even if its being overwritten

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element with inline CSS code in a 'style' attribute. I add a class to this element that overrides the inline styles using `!important` in a CSS stylesheet.

Question: How can I get an inline CSS property value even when it's overridden by CSS from a stylesheet?

When I use `$("div").css("background-size");` It gets the value from the stylesheet CSS, not the inline CSS that's been overwritten.

Comment: jQuery uses computed styles.

Comment: `$("div").attr("style");` it returns the string "inside" the style attribute. check [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0):

Because jQuery uses computedStyles to get the styles applied to elements. I believe that accessing the DOM element could be a *"solution"*

```js
console.log(
  
  $('p').get(0).style.fontSize
  
);
```

```css
p {
   font-size:20px !important; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="font-size:40px;">Hello World</p>
```

You can extend jQuery functions as well.

```js
jQuery.fn.cssInline = function(prop) {
    
    var e = $(this[0]).get(0); // get DOM element
    // convert to camelCase; this may not be required.
    var propCamelCase = prop.replace(/-([a-z])/g, function (g) {
          return g[1].toUpperCase(); 
        });
  
    return e.style[propCamelCase];
  
};

console.log( $('p').cssInline('font-size') );
console.log( $('p').cssInline('fontSize') );
console.log( $('p').cssInline('width') );
```

```css
p {
   font-size:20px !important; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="font-size:40px;">Hello World</p>
```

Comment: At this point jQuery becomes useless. `document.querySelector('p').style.fontSize` is enough.

Comment: Kudos for that! Indeed useless. OP has tagged it tho